# Need help regarding multiple criteria in my where clause

Tags: sql, postgresql

i have a simple query for my dataset:

```
SELECT * FROM efleet_copy
WHERE EXTRACT(MONTH from service_date) = 02
AND status = 'Approved' AND mta_id NOT LIKE '_________'
ORDER BY mta_id;
```

What i need is to exclude transactions that satisfy this conditions:

```
provider = MTA CURB APP which is mta_id = 1
provider = MTA CURB APP Streethail which is mta_id = 1
provider = MTA CONCIERGE which is mta_id = 2
```

This is the sample data:

[image]

I already tried these queries in my where clauses but it didn't work:

```
AND provider IN ('MTA CURB APP', 'MTA CURB APP Streethail') AND mta_id <> '1'
AND provider IN ('MTA CONCIERGE') AND mta_id <> '2'
```

and

```
AND (provider = 'MTA CURB APP' AND mta_id <> '1') OR (provider = 'MTA CURB APP Streethail' AND mta_id <> '1') OR (provider = 'MTA CONCIERGE' AND mta_id <> '2')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
WHERE EXTRACT(MONTH from service_date) = 2 AND
      status = 'Approved' AND
      mta_id NOT LIKE '_________' AND
      (provider, mta_id) NOT IN ( ('MTA CURB APP', 1),
                                  ('MTA CURB APP Streethail', 1)
                                  ('MTA CONCIERGE', 2)
                                );
ORDER BY mta_id;
```